# TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable

Tags: python

Código python para enviar sms só quando a diferença data da consulta é igual a 7 dias da data do dia atual.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb
import pycurl
import base64
import json
import datetime

date_now = datetime.datetime.now()
seven_days_ago = date_now + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xxx.x.xx", user="xxxx", passwd="xxxxxxx", db="xxxxxx")

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT DataConsulta, Dias, HoraConsulta, HoraSaida, nome, Consulta, centrodb.LocalConsulta.Descricao, Contato FROM centrodb.RegistoConsultas LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.LocalConsulta ON centrodb.LocalConsulta.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.`Local` LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes ON centrodb.utentes.codigoutente = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.Utente LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.DiasSemana ON centrodb.DiasSemana.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.DiaSemana")

myresult = cursor.fetchall()

for linha in myresult:
 DataConsulta = linha[0]
 Dias = linha[1]
 HoraConsulta = linha[2]
 HoraSaida = linha[3]
 nome = linha[4]
 Consulta = linha[5]
 Descricao = linha[6]
 Contato = linha[7]

 if DataConsulta == seven_days_ago():
  if __name__ == "__main__":
   url ="https://dashboard.360nrs.com/api/rest/sms"
   usrPass = "xxxxxx:xxxxxxx"
   data = json.dumps({
   "to":[Contato],
   "from":"CPA",
   "message":"Teste ",
   })
   b64Val = base64.b64encode(usrPass)
   headers=["Accept:Application/json","Authorization:Basic %s"%b64Val]
   c = pycurl.Curl()
   c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
   c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER,headers)
   c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
   c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
   c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
   c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
   c.perform()
   http_code = c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
   print(http_code)
```

Quando executo o script no terminal recebo este erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/var/www/html/wordpress/ensms.py", line 29, in <module>
    if DataConsulta == seven_days_ago(): 
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

Comment: Qual o tipo da variável `DataConsulta`?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss a variável `DataConsulta` é tipo `date`

Comment: Se deveria enviar quando a data é **superior** a 7 dias, por que usou `==` ao invés de `>`?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss porque não é quando é superior, mas sim, quando a diferença é igual a 7 dias, por isso usei o `==`. Editei a pergunta

Comment: "para enviar sms só quando a data da consulta é superior a 7 dias", há escrito exatamente isso na sua pergunta. Lembre-se que *datetime*, como o nome sugere, leva em consideração a data e o horário. Se agora for 2018-12-12 08:16:30, sete dias a mais será 2018-12-19 08:16:30. Se você não executar exatamente nesse segundo, não enviará o SMS.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss então a variável que crio em `datetime`, `seven_days_ago`, tem de ser criada em formato tipo `date`, certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução encontrada.
Como Anderson Carlos Woss referiu em relação à variável `datetime`, então aleterei essa variável para uma variável do tipo `date`.

Variável inicial em `datetime`:

```
date_now = datetime.datetime.now()
seven_days_ago = date_now + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

foi substituída por uma variável `date`:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
data = today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

Assim executa o `if` com a condição de a diferença entre datas de serem iguais a 7 dias, caso não seja não envia a sms.

Answer (score 2):

Você está chamando a variável `seven_days_ago` como se ela fosse uma função (daí o erro dizendo que o objeto `datetime.datetime` não pode ser chamado), remova os parênteses e funcionará.

E respondendo ao seu comentário, o `datetime` retorna um objeto específico e não uma *string*, como acontece na consulta do banco de dados:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> a = datetime.now()
>>> a
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 12, 22, 17, 10, 280298)
>>> b = a + timedelta(days=7)
>>> b
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 19, 22, 17, 10, 280298)
```

Portanto você precisa converter o `datetime` antes de poder compará-lo:

```
>>> b.isoformat()
'2018-12-19T22:17:10.280298'
>>> b.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
'19-12-2018'
```

Neste caso você precisará verificar o formato de data que o banco de dados está retornando para poder formatar a data corretamente (consulte a [documentação deste tipo de dados](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) para saber exatamente como fazê-lo).

Comment: se retirar os parênteses no  `seven_days_ago` se a data estiver com diferença de 7 dias, não envia a sms nem retorna erro e se estiver com mais ou menos de 7 dias também não envia nem retorna erro. Pode ajudar a perceber o problema?

Comment: Você precisa comparar "coisas iguais", veja o complemento que fiz à resposta.